# router-link button doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Alright what I'm trying to make is make a link button that goes to sign-up page from login page. but every time I click the button It doesn't show up any errors and do anything. I have no idea why It's not working It's my first time using vue-router. need help!

```
<template lang="pug">
.wrapper
  .container
    h1 CNTRL
    form(v-on:submit.prevent='onSubmit').form
      input(type='text', placeholder='Username', v-model='id')
      input(type='password', placeholder='Password', v-model='password')
      button(type="button")#login-button Login
      router-link(to="{ path: '/signup' }") // <- this one
        button(type="button")#signup-button Sign-Up  
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Electron from 'vue-electron'
import Resource from 'vue-resource'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import App from './App'
import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(Electron)
Vue.use(Resource)
Vue.use(Router)
Vue.config.debug = true

const router = new Router({
  routes
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  router,
  ...App
}).$mount('#app')
```

**routes.js**

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/signup',
    name: 'signup',
    component: require('components/SignUpView')
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'landing-page',
    component: require('components/LandingPageView')
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/'
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you have a router-view somewhere?

Comment: @BertEvans No I don't

Comment: Then nothing will happen :) router-view is the component that *shows* the current route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<router-link :to="{ path: 'home' }">Home</router-link>`

I think you can try to add 'v-bind:' or ':' before 'to' property.

I recommend you see vue-router Docs more.

Comment: sorry, it is 'v-bind:', not 'v-on:'.